# Toast no funciona en Bootstrap-Vue-3

Tags: vue3, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

Intento utilizar el componente toast de [Bootstrap-Vue-3](https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/components/Toast.html) según la documentación, pero el pluging parece no inyectarse a la aplicación.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import { BToastPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(BootstrapVue3);
app.use(BToastPlugin);
app.mount('#app');
```

**App.vue**

```javascript
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    addToast(append = false) {
      this.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast`, {
        title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
        autoHideDelay: 5000,
        appendToast: append,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Obtengo: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toast')**

**Aquí el código:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-shaw-qkzkn2?file=/src/App.vue

**Dependencias:**

- vue == 3.2.37
- bootstrap == 5.2.0
- bootstrap-vue-3 == 0.2.8

Answer (score 1):

Lo conseguí utilizando [useToast](https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/components/Toast.html#variants)

```javascript
import { useToast } from 'bootstrap-vue-3';

export default {
  name: "App",
  sutup() {
    const toast = useToast();
    return { toast };
  },
  methods: {
    addToast(append = false) {
      if (this.toast) {
        this.toast.show({
          title: "This is toast",
          body: "This is toast body"
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
```